# Using context name in django is not working Dataframe.to_html()

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a problem following one tutorial on displaying dataframes in django web page
my Views.py is as follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from products.models import Product
import pandas as pd

def chart_select_view(request):
product_df = pd.DataFrame(Product.objects.all().values())
context = {
    'Products': product_df,
}
return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

I have two errors the first is unable to import pandas as pd and I've already installed it in my venv

the second is not important but here it is
"object has no members" and I know it's a pylint error

when I want to show Products in the main.html it displays error
"Invalid block tag on line 9: 'Products', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

the main.html is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} {% endblock title %}



{% block content %} 
<h1>Hello World</h1>
{% Products %}


{% endblock content %}
```

Can somebody help I'm following the tutorial perfectly but it shows an error to me when it's working fine in the video.

Comment: You work with `{{ Products }}` (so with two curly brackets), not `{% Products %}`.

Comment: Omg I'm so dumb thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You render a variable by surrounding it with *double* curly brackets, so `{{ … }}`, not <s>`{% … %}`</s>.

If you want to render it nicely, you can work with [**`.to_html()`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html), and mark it as safe to prevent escaping the tags with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html):

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello World</h1>
{{ Products.to_html|safe }}
{% endblock content %}
```